# What is the "Spanish_ar" localization option that programs offer while installing?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, informática

When installing programs with language options, I frequently see the localization option "Spanish_ar" in addition to regular Spanish. What locality of Spanish does this refer to? I'd expect something that referred in some way to Castilian or Latin America but "ar" seems mysterious to me.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to know in addition what the differences are

Comment: So funny that that's the only variant offered!

Comment: Closing since it is not about the Spanish language but about computing.

Comment: Voting to reopen because I think it's a fair question.  If OP had asked some actual content question in this context, then we wouldn't have been able to answer it, without delving into the content area.  But in this case, we didn't need to have an Information Technology specialty to be able to give a useful answer.

Comment: I agree with @aparente001 in this case. The question is more or less equivalent to *Is there a Spanish variation known as Spanish_ar*, which is about linguistics and not computing. The question just gives some context as to where did OP find that variation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15596/what-is-spanish_ar-which-spanish-is-latin-am-spanish) it's stated that it refers to “Español argentina”, at least for notepad++.

Comment: Thank you. That's interesting and unexpected as I've never seen a listed variation of Spanish specific to Argentina.